# default wraptext for lightning-tree-grid cell

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

I see there is a `wrapText` by default support for datatables in Aura and LWC. Would like to post this question on a broader platform and see if there is a way to default `wrapText` in `lightning-tree-grid` or in `lightning:treeGrid` as a `cellAttribute`

I did an IdeaExchange post here for this.
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000chvKQAQ